# Concavity of log function for proof of Young's Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

So I am looking at the solution for the proof of Young's Inequality and I notice the following statement, that I am failing to process. Please note that $p \in (1,\infty)$ and $q:=\frac{p}{p+1}$, i.e. $1/p+1/q=1$.

Why is this statement true?

$$\log{\left(\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{y^q}{q}\right)} \geq \frac{1}{p}\log{x^p}+\frac{1}{q}\log{y^q}$$

Comment: Note that $\frac1p\log(x^p)=\log(x)$ and similar for the other term. Also, is $x,y>0$?

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that. But still, how would the LHS be more or equal than $logx +logy$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the logarithm is a concave function, as its derivative $\frac1x$ is strictly decreasing. A property of concave functions $f(x)$ is the following:

[image: concave fuction]

Say you have two points, $x<y$. Then, if $0<a<1$, we know that $(1-a)x+ay$ is a number between $x$ and $y$. Thus, for concave functions, if we draw a line from $(x,f(x))$ to $(y,f(y))$, it must lie completely below the function itself; thus, since $x<(1-a)x+ay<y$, we know $((1-a)x+ay,f((1-a)x+ay))$ must lie *above* the line from $(x,f(x))$ to $(y,f(y))$. The point on that line with x-coordinate $(1-a)x+ay$ is $((1-a)x+ay,(1-a)f(x)+af(y))$, and so the inequality

$$(1-a)f(x)+af(y)\leq f((1-a)x+ay)$$
arises. Since $\log$ is a concave function, we know that
$$(1-a)\log(x)+a\log(y)\leq \log((1-a)x+ay)$$
and with $1-a=\frac1p$ and $a=\frac1q$, using the inequality on $x^p$ and $y^q$ rather than $x$ and $y$, this becomes
$$\frac1p\log(x^p)+\frac1q\log(y^q)\leq \log(\frac1px^p+\frac1qy^q)$$
exactly what we wanted.